# Automate running vba code on excel file via Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

OS: Windows 10, 1903
Office: Office 2016
Powershell:  5.1

I have an excel file we'll call *records.xlsm* that gets automatically downloaded every day.  I need to do things to that file and then send it on someplace else.  I have created the necessary VBA code to automate this and that code resides in a .bas file we'll call *cleanup.bas* .

I'm attempting to find a way to use Powershell or some other canned Microsoft tool to automate running the vba code against the file.  I haven't found a way (that I like) to do this yet with Powershell.

My goal is to use task scheduler to run a Powershell script to make the changes in *records.xlsm* using the code from *cleanup.bas*.

I don't mind if *cleanup.bas* has to be imported into *records.xlsm* but that process must also be automated too.

I assume it's possible.  I'm asking to confirm / deny if it is or not.  If possible, please tell me where I need to start looking documentation-wise.

I found code from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/f3bcd564-d7e0-4a80-bf4e-120eefc8ccd1/using-powershell-to-add-vba-to-an-excel-spreadsheet?forum=winserverpowershell). I don't mind going that route, but it seems not so elegant.  Practicality trumps Pretty though, so I'll use it if nothing else works.

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false

$workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\test.xls")
$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

$code = @"
sub cleanup()
'your code goes here
end sub
"@

$xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($code)
```

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Easiest route would be to place your VBA in a standalone Excel xlsm file, which you can open after you've opened your source file - then use `Application.Run` to run the macro, passing in the name of your source workbook as the "target" for the code.

Comment: Thanks for the time, but we don't do easy around here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying in that comment - that you want to do it the way you posted?  If that's the case then why not try it out?

Comment: As for this ... "I'm attempting to find a way to use Powershell or some other canned Microsoft tool to automate running the VBA code against the file. I haven't found a way (that I like) to do this yet with Powershell."... it is a very opinionated thing. Thus setting you up for an opinion debate. Only you know what you will and won't like. So you are literally asking for a bunch of ideas from folks, so you can make that determination when a bunch of ideas already exist on SO and all over the web.

Comment: PowerShell talks to the MSOffice app via COM, as you are using. Why bring stand-alone VBA into the mix. Just take the VBA use case and covert that to PowerShell to run against the file via COM directly? Why overcomplicate this use case, just because? Don't increase your core workload unnecessarily and then dump this on those that will follow you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with setting up macros in Office applications. But I've often run VBS against Outlook COM objects, which turns out to be very similar to the VBA code.  That said, PowerShell can instantiate COM objects!  I've seen many people do the same sort of thing purely inside PowerShell, including for Excel.  In this paradigm it wouldn't really be a macro, but an external script that cracks open the XLSX file makes the modifications and save it back.

My advice would be to check out the [ImportExcel PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.2), which you can find on the Gallery.  It's very capable, doesn't require that Excel be installed and it's more of a first class citizen than COM.  I realize that might entail a significant rewrite on your end, but my bet is you'll be happier with the final product.

Comment: I'll look into it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No worries, but my point was what Steven reiterated, avoid the need to call the `.bas` file at all. Just covert the `.bas` to COM calls from PowerShell, to Excel. It's why COM exists, and since you have to use COM to interop with anything MSOffice related, then, why not just use it. PowerShell only runs `.ps*` files, any external stuff must be called/processed by the owner of that thing. In your case Excel VBA engine.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

Yet, if you'd search (never stop at the first one you find) the SO post, via the search box above; you'll see similar Q&A on the use case you say you want.

> [How to use VBA Code inside a Powershell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631170/how-to-use-vba-code-inside-a-powershell-script)

Or just a web search:

> https://www.excell-en.com/blog/2018/8/20/powershell-run-macros-copy-files-do-cool-stuff-with-power
>
> https://powershelladministrator.com/2017/12/20/open-excel-file-and-run-macro/

Idea's and likability of a resolution, if there is one, comes from personal research.

***Update:***

Continuing from my comment, as of your last comment to me.

You can read any text-based file into PowerShell, That does not mean PowerShell can run it. External code must be ran using the needed parsing engine. Again, in your use case the MSOffie VBA engine.

I could refactor your code to call a serialized .bas file this way.

```
$xl               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible       = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false

$workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\test.xls")
$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

$VbaCode = (Get-Content -Path '$PWD\SomeCode.bas' -Raw)

$xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($VbaCode)
```

***Update***

One more item is that, if you do not have these two keys...

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -Value 1 -Force | 
Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -Value 1 -Force | 
Out-Null
```

...set on the host you are trying to do this on, this...

```
$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
```

...will fail anyway because the VBComponents do not exist until you set them.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll attempt to improve my search skills....  I've already been to those links.  It won't work the way I want.  I'll review how I ask questions and how I search in an attempt to not waste anyone's time around here.

Comment: I presume that you must also presume I am pretty piss poor at searching and thinking in general (based on your replies and posts).  I'm going to chalk it up to me not being able to effectively articulate what I want.
  
Long story short, calling directly from COM via powershell may very well be the best way to go, but putting the vba code directly into the powershell script saves so much more time and is still the most practical route to go - at this time, for me.