# Unable to run macro in my corporate machine no matter what I do

Tags: java, vba, excel

I have an excel macro saved locally (.xlsm file ) and I have kept a macro which runs as soon as we open the excel file and this macro is running flawlessly when manually clicking on the excel file and opening. But, when I am trying to open the same excel file using the below java code, the excel is opening fine but the macro which is programmed to run on opening the excel is not getting triggered and excel is taking very long time to open, it seems as if something is taking time in trying to restrict the macro first and then allowing the excel to open. I have enabled all settings under excel trust centre still the macro is never getting triggered through the below java code. Kindly help me with your expert advices. Thanks in advance.

Java code used :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.exe C:\\do_something.xlsm");
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Running java code from IDE or jar file?

Comment: I am running java code using Eclipse Mars2.0

Comment: Try to restart eclipse with Run as Admin privileges.

Comment: By the way, it is a Maven project

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always run the macro by accessing it this way: `'<workbook>'!<module name where the UDF sits>.<UDF name>`

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks for your response. Can you pls provide the complete command?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789780/how-to-call-an-excel-vba-macro-from-java-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi Shanu, I tried restarting eclipse with admin privilege, still macro is not opening :(

Comment: Also, if you want to ask someone a question here, if you add "**@**" sign infront of their name, they get a notification (i.e. **@Zac**).. just a tip :)

Comment: Thanks Zac, trying to do that.

Comment: @ShanuGupta I tried restarting eclipse with admin privilege, still macro is not opening :(

Comment: Have you tried `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("inputFilePath"));`?

Comment: Thanks @GMalc for your response. I just tried it and there were no compile time errrors , however, there was a run time error : "java.awt.HeadlessException: null at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Unknown Source)"

Comment: What is the file path you are using?

Comment: @GMalc C:\\do_something.xlsm

Comment: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/workbook_open-vs-auto_open/    - see section on automation: that may be relevant here