# How to run exiting macros in an excel - using POI library in java code

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel with few macros in it. I want to run these macros from JAVA program using POI library.

I verified the available classes in POI library. But it seems there are no classes available in POI library to do this task.

Any suggestion to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since VBA is hosted, you need an instance of Excel to run these. POI is for reading and writing.

Comment: Thanks Bigben, But how to get instance of an excel which has macros. 
Is there any way to get it from java code.  And how to call macros from that instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_How to call an Excel VBA Macro from Java Code?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789780/230513)