# Apache POI 5.2.2 : How to draw a XSSFSimpleShape based on Offsets and Dimensions in Centimeters?

Tags: xssf

I want to draw shapes in Excel with Java, using measurements in Centimeter :
offset in cm from left side,
offset in cm from top side,
width in cm,
height in cm.

The Apache POI 5.2.2 looks good for this. I saw the XSSFClientAnchor class.

Several XSSFClientAnchor examples are available, but they deal with measurements in (point, characters, columns numbers, rows numbers).
See e.g. [this question](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=48567203),
the [getting started code](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

I tried several codes based on examples, but I very often get unexpected results.
Could you please help to convert (offset, width and height) to (point, charachters, columns,rows) ?
Thank you very much.

Additional info :
In the past I programmed Excel VBA macros to draw shapes.
I used this code to draw a shape, based on offsets and dimensions in centimeters.
The function Shapes.AddShape(...) takes as input values in "points," which can be computed from "centimeters*28.34646".

VBA code :

```
Sub drawer1()
    Dim sShape1 As Shape

    dDeltaLeftCm = ConvertCmToPoint(100)
    dDeltaTopCm = 0
    dWidthCm = ConvertCmToPoint(50)
    dHeightCm = ConvertCmToPoint(10)
    
    Set sShape1 = Application.Sheets(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, dDeltaLeftCm, dDeltaTopCm, dWidthCm, dHeightCm)
End Sub

Function ConvertCmToPoint(ByVal cm As Double) As Double
    ConvertCmToPoint = cm * 28.34646
End Function
```

In Vba, my code behaved as expected.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I will use my old Vba code, pass to it the parameters in centimeters, and run it from Java, using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789780/how-to-call-an-excel-vba-macro-from-java-code